# OpenIddict error with AddSigningCertificate

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, x509certificate2, openiddict

I am trying to signin certificate (OpenIddict), but I get error when trying with thumbprint:

```
options.AddSigningCertificate(Configuration["Certificate"]/* db b9 12 .... 22 */);
```

and the error:

> Application startup exception:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: OpenCSP failed
>   with error code 2148073494.

in this line:

```
app.UseOpenIddict();
```

If I tried with X509Certificate2 I also get error:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Configuration["Certificate"]/*path to file.cer*/);
options.AddSigningCertificate(cert);
```

and the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The certificate doesn't contain the
>   required private key.

in same line `app.UseOpenIddict();`.

I am using the same certificate that I am using for https protocol. Is this OK?
My active tokens are randomly gone (and I get invalid_token when trying to refresh the token). I find somewhere that this happens if `AddEphemeralSigningKey` is used, because when connection is dropped (because of IIS idle timeout), all tokens are lost. Because of that I am trying to use `AddSigningCertificate`.

Is there another way? Can someone tell me, what is wrong with certificate? Thank you.

I am using ASP.NET Core 1.1.1.
I add read rights to IIS user for .cer file.

[image: certificate]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem with new certificate created with SelfCert (https://s3.amazonaws.com/pluralsight-free/keith-brown/samples/SelfCert.zip).
I then added certificate to project source and call AddSigningCertificate:

```
            if (this.env.IsDevelopment())
                options.AddEphemeralSigningKey();      
            else
                options.AddSigningCertificate(new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Resources/cert.pfx", FileMode.Open), "pass");
```

I also had to add **full** rights to file for IIS user. Read and execute right was not enough.

And that's it. It works.

Comment: Using a separate certificate is indeed the right thing to do. Note: you should consider storing it in the machine store. The error you were seeing was likely caused by the fact the IIS app pool identity was not allowed to access the private key. You can read http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2012/02/grant-iis-75-access-to-certificate-in.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

For use a cert in the machine personal store.

You must give permisions to the app pool of the site.

Go to machine certficate manager.

In the personal folder right click the certificate and select
`All Task>Manage private keys` (not sure the options in english, my os is spanish)

In the security window add the app pool user, you can see it in the basic configuration of your site or aplication

```
IIS APPPOOL\here_your_app_pool_name
```

then can use it in the Startup with

```
 options.AddSigningCertificate("here cert thumbprint, look for it in cert info");
```

Comment: Also see [Certificate thumbprint displayed in MMC certificate snap-in has extra invisible unicode character](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/certificate-thumbprint-displayed-in-mmc-certificate-snap-in-has-extra-invisible-unicode-character-c9e58dcb-f39a-d0a1-f7fc-bcaaa6fe64e4) when copying thumbprint.